# Strip span and put into input

Tags: jquery

This should be pretty simple - Get content from a `h1` tag, strip the `span` tag and put the remaining into a `input` tag

**I have this HTML:**

```
<div id="contentArea">
    <h1><span>Course</span>Arrangementname<h1>
    <input type="hidden" id="arr1Form_Arrangement" name="arr1Form_Arrangement">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').html();
eventname.find("span").remove();
var eventnametrim = eventname.html();
//alert(eventnametrim);
$( "input[name*='Form_Arrangement']" ).val( eventnametrim );
```

But nothing happens - the alert is also empty. My firebug tells me that 
`"eventname.find is not a function"` it's jQuery 1.9.0

Can someone please telle me whats going on?

Comment: You were trying to run a jQuery method on an html string because `var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired output is `Arrangementname` then the problem is the first line, which should be:

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1');
```

...because that makes `eventname` a jQuery object, on which you can use `.find()` to get the span and remove it with your existing second line. Though that actually removes the span element from the page completely, so you might want to do this:

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').clone();
```

...so that you have a working copy that won't affect what is displayed on the page.

The next problem is that you have a variable called `eventnametrim` that you then refer to on the last line of your code as `$eventnametrim`. Remove the `$` from the latter so the names match.

If you're trying to get an output of `CourseArrangementname`, i.e., to ignore the `<span>` and `</span>` tags but keep the text content, you can do it like this:

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').text();
$( "input[name*='Form_Arrangement']" ).val( eventname );
```

Answer (score 1):

then just use:

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').text();
$( "input[name*='Form_Arrangement']" ).val( eventname );
```

Using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instad of  [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and eventname will contain the text without html ;)

because if you remove the span, then you are removing the tag and its content (the text that you want)

Comment: I want to delete the <span> with contents. But thanks, that I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `html()`:

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').text();
$( "input[name*='Form_Arrangement']" ).val( $.trim(eventname ));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X8nU2/)**

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1');
```

html is not a jQuery object, I believe, is what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error in the console. Try something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GmzXG/

```
$('#contentArea h1').find("span").remove();
var eventname = $('#contentArea h1').html();

//alert(eventnametrim);
$( "input[name*='Form_Arrangement']" ).val( eventname );
```